# Can we use exoplayer to render a video on a opengl SurfaceTexture?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

Can we use exoplayer to render a video on a opengl SurfaceTexture like we can do with mediaPlayer? I need this because i want to draw each frame of the video on a OpenGL texture ...

Answer (score 1):

```
class SurfaceTextureWrapper extends SurfaceTexture {

    public SurfaceTextureWrapper() {
        super(genSurfaceTexture());
    }


    private static int genSurfaceTexture() {
        int[] args = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(args.length, args, 0);
        int textureHandle = args[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureHandle);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);


        return textureHandle;
    }

}
```

usage sample

```
exoPlayer.setVideoSurface(new Surface(new SurfaceTextureWrapper());
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes you can. I don't know whether you have resolved the issue but you can do that with surfaceTexture.

```
surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(yourOpenGlTextureId);
Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
```

do what you usually do to set up your exoPlayer

```
exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer...
```

and then simply

```
exoPlayer.setVideoSurface(surface);
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Render works, but the ratio is not right, even you have set
videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING